# Slow DB procedure after migrate table from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mariadb, slow-query

EDITED: We have table XXXX and DB procedure DB_PROD which select data from table XXXX to cursor and then insert or update other tables.

Insert to table XXXX is single transaction for each row - this is very fast.
Before call db procedure we do:
SET ISOLATION LEVEL to SERIALIZE to get max id where c3 = YY.
The same isolation level we are setting for DELETE query to remove rows where id <= max AND c3 = YY.

We migrated table XXXX from MyISAM to InnoDB and in procedure I added condition:

```
        IF LENGTH(_tagIds) > 0 AND _tagIds <> 'NO_TAG' THEN
            SET import = 'A';
        ELSEIF _optout IS TRUE THEN
            SET import = 'B';
        ELSE
            SET import = 'C';
        END IF;
```

Can anyone tell me what could happen that from this moment DB procedure is slower. We only updated DB procedure which has additional variables set like above and we change XXXX table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Table XXXX schema (sorry but I can't add real column name):

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `XXXX` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `c2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobId` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `c2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob NOT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `c2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `jobId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=380806123 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For each selected for form XXXX table to cursor we are updating/inserting 5/6 tables with single query - there is no transaction for a few query.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  When you "insert or update" other tables, are you doing such one row at a time (very slow) or batched (much faster)?